# Why perl does not tend to gobble up all the arguments that follow it?

Tags: perl

Acording to [doc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Terms-and-List-Operators-%28Leftward%29) **list operators tend to gobble up all arguments that follow**

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
#sub test;
#sub My::test;

sub list {
   print ">>@_<<\n";
}

sub new {
   my $class =  shift;
   my $self =  bless {}, 'main';
   list 0, main::test $self, 1, 2, 3;
   list 0, My::test $self, 1, 2, 3;
}

# sub test (@) { # it has not matter there is prototype or not
sub test {
   print "test>>@_<<\n";
   return;
}

new();

package My;

# sub test (@) { # it has not matter there is prototype or not
sub test {
   print "My::test>>@_<<\n";
   return;
}
```

In this example the output is:

```
test>>main=HASH(0x24a3160)<<
>>0 1 2 3<<
My::test>>main=HASH(0x24a3160)<<
>>0 1 2 3<<
```

Which means that list does not gobble up all the arguments that follow it
**The expecting result is:**

```
test>>main=HASH(0x1bea160) 1 2 3<<
>>0<<
My::test>>main=HASH(0x1bea160) 1 2 3<<
>>0<<
```

What a problem is?

Comment: You don't have a list operator. Printing `@_` does not operate **on it**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why you expected the different result. For better understanding, I changed the `test`s to return `t` from main and `m` from `My`, turning the output to

```
test>>main=HASH(0x60003b650)<<
>>0 t 1 2 3<<
My::test>>main=HASH(0x60003b650)<<
>>0 m 1 2 3<<
```

Did you think test would eat all the arguments? You can't do that with methods, you need normal subroutines for that. Your syntax is equivalent to

```
list(0, $self->main::test(), 1, 2, 3);
```

Try changing your code to

```
list(0, main::test 1, 2, 3);
list(0, My::test 1, 2, 3);
```

but you'll have to move `sub test` declarations upwards, or predeclare the subs (plain `sub test;` with no block). That's why using parentheses with subroutines is a good practice.

**Update:** Moving `sub test` declarations upwards works for your code, too. The parser must know a subroutine to be able to parse it as such.

Comment: I expect it to be: `list(0, main::test ($self, 1, 2, 3));` I do not try to use indirect call, because I have ',' after $self

Comment: Look at [example](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Terms-and-List-Operators-%28Leftward%29): `@ary = (1, 3, sort 4, 2);`

Comment: @EugenKonkov: Run your script through `perl -MO=Deparse,-p`. Perl understands the syntax as indirect call - you declare `test` too late.